# XML/XSLT sum for-each with variables

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, foreach, sum

I am having a problem. What I want is to sum the objects and print them for every iteration. I am new to XSLT, so please be kind. What I have is this code:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "Windows-1252"?>
<GPDUMP>
  <ROUTE>
    <ALL_ROUTEANDORDER>
      <NUMBER>3</NUMBER>
      <NO0>
        <ROUTEANDORDER>
          <FKCUSTOMERID>2</FKCUSTOMERID>
          <SEQUENCENO>1</SEQUENCENO>
          <STOPNO>1</STOPNO>
          <SPLITKMDRIVING>13076</SPLITKMDRIVING>
        </ROUTEANDORDER>
      </NO0>
      <NO1>
        <ROUTEANDORDER>
          <FKCUSTOMERID>4</FKCUSTOMERID>
          <SEQUENCENO>2</SEQUENCENO>
          <STOPNO>2</STOPNO>
          <SPLITKMDRIVING>6204</SPLITKMDRIVING>
        </ROUTEANDORDER>
      </NO1>
      <NO2>
        <ROUTEANDORDER>
          <FKCUSTOMERID>3</FKCUSTOMERID>
          <SEQUENCENO>3</SEQUENCENO>
          <STOPNO>3</STOPNO>
          <SPLITKMDRIVING>4775</SPLITKMDRIVING>
        </ROUTEANDORDER>
      </NO2>
    </ALL_ROUTEANDORDER>
  </ROUTE>
</GPDUMP>
```

What I want as output is something like this:

```
<CUSTOMERID>2</CUSTOMERID>
<DIST_FROM_PREVIOUS>13076</DIST_FROM_PREVIOUS>
<DIST_FROM_START>13076</DIST_FROM_START>

<CUSTOMERID>4</CUSTOMERID>
<DIST_FROM_PREVIOUS>6204</DIST_FROM_PREVIOUS>
<DIST_FROM_START>13076 + 6204</DIST_FROM_START>

<CUSTOMERID>3</CUSTOMERID>
<DIST_FROM_PREVIOUS>4775</DIST_FROM_PREVIOUS>
<DIST_FROM_START>13076 + 6204 + 4775</DIST_FROM_START>
```

As you can see, the `DIST_FROM_START` should be summed as the process follows.

What I have is this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ALL_ROUTEANDORDER[1]/*[$index]" >
  <xsl:variable name="kmFromStart" select="sum(ALL_ROUTEANDORDER/*[starts-with(name(),'NO')]/ROUTEANDORDER/SPLITKMDRIVING)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="kmFromPrevious" select="ALL_ROUTEANDORDER/*[starts-with(name(),'NO')]/ROUTEANDORDER/SPLITKMDRIVING"/>
  <xsl:text>From start</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$kmFromStart" />
  <xsl:text>From previous </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$kmFromPrevious" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Hope someone gets my idea, and can help me! I have googled several pages and also tried with parameters with no luck. I am really desperate to get this to work! Any help is apreciated! THANKS :)

Comment: The output you say you want has no root node, and so is invalid XML. Also, do you *really* want the three customers and their details all at the same level? It more usual to have a `<CUSTOMER>` node that has, say, an `id` attribute and two child elements that hold the information. Also do you want the additions literally like that or do you want them calculated before they are inserted?

Comment: Also, is there only *one* `/GPDUMP/ROUTE/ALL_ROUTEANDORDER` element in the whole data, or do you want this doing for several elements?

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of any guidance as to your exact requirements, I have written this. I hope it helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/GPDUMP/ROUTE/ALL_ROUTEANDORDER">
    <root>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#x0A;'"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'NO')]"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'NO')]">

    <xsl:variable name="routes" select="(self::*|preceding-sibling::*[starts-with(local-name(), 'NO')])/ROUTEANDORDER/SPLITKMDRIVING"/>

    <CUSTOMERID>
      <xsl:value-of select="ROUTEANDORDER/FKCUSTOMERID"/>
    </CUSTOMERID>
    <DIST_FROM_PREVIOUS>
      <xsl:value-of select="ROUTEANDORDER/SPLITKMDRIVING"/>
    </DIST_FROM_PREVIOUS>
    <DIST_FROM_START>
      <xsl:value-of select="sum($routes)"/>
    </DIST_FROM_START>

    <xsl:value-of select="'&#x0A;'"/>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>

   <CUSTOMERID>2</CUSTOMERID>
   <DIST_FROM_PREVIOUS>13076</DIST_FROM_PREVIOUS>
   <DIST_FROM_START>13076</DIST_FROM_START>

   <CUSTOMERID>4</CUSTOMERID>
   <DIST_FROM_PREVIOUS>6204</DIST_FROM_PREVIOUS>
   <DIST_FROM_START>19280</DIST_FROM_START>

   <CUSTOMERID>3</CUSTOMERID>
   <DIST_FROM_PREVIOUS>4775</DIST_FROM_PREVIOUS>
   <DIST_FROM_START>24055</DIST_FROM_START>

</root>
```